# Extract string between parentheses

Tags: sed

I've been trying to extract the substring in between parentheses (including parentheses) from:

```
"WHITE-TAILED TROPIC-BIRD _Phaëthon lepturus_ (Hawaiian name—koae)"
```

I tried this:

```
str=$(echo $1 | sed 's/.*\(\([^)]*\)\).*/\1/');
echo $str
```

What I wanted to get was:

```
"(Hawaiian name—koae)"
```

However, I've been getting an error called:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: It's a problem with your bash syntax. Check your code and your posting here.

Comment: Btw.: I suggest to replace `$1` with `"$1"`.

Comment: Copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and it'll tell you about most if not all of your problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -n 's/.*\(([^()]*)\).*/\1/p'
```

Here,

- `-n` - suppresses default line output
- `.*\(([^()]*)\).*` - matches any text, then captures into Group 1 a `(`, then 0 or more chars other than `(` and `)`, then a `)`, and then again `.*` matches any text to the end of the string
- `/\1/` - replaces the whole match with the contents of Group 1
- `p` - prints the result.

**See [online demo](https://ideone.com/oQtYGP)**

In a script called `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
str=$(echo "$1" | sed -n 's/.*\(([^()]*)\).*/\1/p');
echo "$str"
```

Called like

```
bash ./script.sh "WHITE-TAILED TROPIC-BIRD _Phaëthon lepturus_ (Hawaiian name—koae)"
```

Result: `(Hawaiian name—koae)`

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. I still get the same error.

Comment: @Mert See [the online demo](https://ideone.com/oQtYGP), it works. You must probably have an issue somewhere else.

Comment: Well, it works if I use the string as a variable but if I use it as a parameter, it gives me the same error. I have no idea why it's hapenning.

Comment: No, I don't use any functions.

Comment: `if I use the string as a variable but if I use it as a parameter,` Please create an [MCVE]. The error most probably is in the "use it as a parameter" part, which you are not presenting to us.

Comment: @KamilCuk What I input the console is: ./script.sh WHITE-TAILED TROPIC-BIRD _Phaëthon lepturus_ (Hawaiian name—koae)

Comment: @Mert See an example above, my suggestion still works.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "WHITE-TAILED TROPIC-BIRD _Phaëthon lepturus_ (Hawaiian name—koae)" | \
cut -d'_' -f3 | sed s'@^ @@'
```

If you've got good delimiters, then it is much easier to get parts of lines with cut, than with sed.  I only really use sed for replacing characters when I know exactly where they are.  For more complex operations, I will usually have to get a piece of text out of the file by inserting carriage returns before and after it with ed, (thus putting it on its' own line, which I can then rip out easily) make the minor changes to it that I want with sed, and then use ed to put it back in.